# Download Email attachment using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I would like to Download Email attachment using SSIS.If possible,Please describe the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use third-party solutions, check the commercial [CozyRoc SSIS+](http://www.cozyroc.com) library. It includes **Receive Mail Task**, which can download email form POP3 and IMAP servers. Saving of email attachments is also supported.